# Set numeric property to move by reference - C#

Tags: c#, recursion, reference

I have the next object (Tree structured Object):

```
public class someClass
{

ObservableCollection<someClass> Children { get; }
long NumOfSelectedChildren { get; set; }
}

//There is more properties but its not important for my question
```

I need to scan a given "someClass" Object and set for every node into the property NumOfSelectedChildrenthe number Of his children.

I wrote some recursion that do this task but I must send the NumOfSelectedChildren proprty as reference. Currently, when my recursion finished all the "NumOfSelectedChildren" properties are equal to 0 because the recursion move the parameters by value and not by reference.

When I`m trying to send the property as "ref" I get the following error:
"Error  23  A property, indexer or dynamic member access may not be passed as an out or ref parameter"

How can I make sure that this property will be sent by reference and not by value?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You haven't shown how you update the `NumOfSelectedChildren` property, so let me propose an alternate solution that doesn't require you to pass a property by reference:

```
public class someClass
{
    ObservableCollection<someClass> Children { get; }

    long NumOfSelectedChildren { get; set; }

    int UpdateNumOfSelectedChildren()
    {
       return NumOfSelectedChildren =
           Children.Sum(x => 1 + x.UpdateNumOfSelectedChildren());
    }
}
```